# how to retrieve AWS ResourceARN for ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to add billing tags to AWS resources like VPC, EBS snapshots, ELBs and EC2s using ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI but can't find generic resource arns for each service.
Tags are to be added across all the AWS regions.
what I tried:

```
def tagresources(region):
tagapi = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi',region_name=region)
tagapi.tag_resources(
    ResourceARNList=[
        'arn:aws::ec2::vpc',
    ],
    Tags={
        'key_name': 'value'
    }
)
```

which threw error:

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the TagResources operation: arn:aws::ec2::vpc is not a valid AmazonResourceName (ARN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the full ARN for VPC.
[Services that support the Resource Groups Tagging API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)

```
ResourceARNList=[
        'arn:aws:ec2:eu-central-1:111111111111:vpc/vpc-09dddb42be54c1111'
    ],
```